# Reset a counter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code to compile jobs from github jobs API.  How do I reset a counter back to 0 every time I call on a new city?  I've tried putting it in several different places with no luck.

```
def ft_count_and_percentage
    @@url += @city
    uri = URI(@@url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    result = JSON.parse(response)
    result.each do |job|
        if job["type"] == "Full Time"
            @@fulltime_count += 1
        end
    end 
    puts "Total number of jobs in #{@city}: #{result.length}"
    if @@fulltime_count > 0
        puts ("full time percent ") + "#{(@@fulltime_count/result.length) * 100}"
    else
        puts "No FT Positions"
    end 
end
```

@@fulltime_count is defined outside this method to start at 0.  Currently, as expected the counter just keeps adding jobs every time I add a new city.

```
    boston = Job.new("Boston")
boston.ft_count_and_percentage
sf = Job.new("San Francisco")
sf.ft_count_and_percentage
la = Job.new("Los Angeles")
la.ft_count_and_percentage
denver = Job.new("Denver")
denver.ft_count_and_percentage
boulder = Job.new("Boulder")
boulder.ft_count_and_percentage
chicago = Job.new("Chicago")
chicago.ft_count_and_percentage
ny = Job.new("New York City")
ny.ft_count_and_percentage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to reset it inside Job init

```
class Job
  def initialize
    @@count = 0
  end

  def ft_count_and_percentage
    #the blah you already have
  end
end
```